# jQuery show/hide return undefined, break plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In the past week, I've had jCrop, infinite scroll, and jQuery UI have all broken on me, with an error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'x' of undefined". I've tracked all of the errors to a line something like `$el.hide().chain(stuff);` For some reason, show and hide aren't returning anything.

I downloaded an uncompressed copy of the jQuery 2.0.3 file and started putting in console logs and it gets really weird. In the showHide and the show/hide functions in the jQuery file, the return values are defined. However, it seems like the jQuery collection gets lost as soon as it leaves the show/hide functions. Here's an example of me testing it in Chrome's browser console.

```
console.log( $("#curate [name='series']") )
[input.ui-autocomplete-input, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document,     selector: "#curate [name='series']", jquery: "2.0.3", constructor: function…] VM4093:2
undefined

console.log( $("#curate [name='series']").show() )
inside showHide jquery-2.0.3.js:6164
[input.ui-autocomplete-input, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document, selector: "#curate [name='series']", jquery: "2.0.3", constructor: function…] jquery-2.0.3.js:6165
Inside show jquery-2.0.3.js:6194
[input.ui-autocomplete-input, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document, selector: "#curate [name='series']", jquery: "2.0.3", constructor: function…] jquery-2.0.3.js:6195
undefined VM4094:2
undefined

console.log( $("#curate [name='series']").show().val() )
inside showHide jquery-2.0.3.js:6164
[input.ui-autocomplete-input, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document, selector: "#curate [name='series']", jquery: "2.0.3", constructor: function…] jquery-2.0.3.js:6165
Inside show jquery-2.0.3.js:6194
[input.ui-autocomplete-input, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document, selector: "#curate [name='series']", jquery: "2.0.3", constructor: function…] jquery-2.0.3.js:6195
TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of undefined
```

What could possibly be happening here? The elements seem to disappear as soon as they leave the show/hide functions. Could another javascript library interfere with jQuery in such a way to produce this result? You can see my modified version of the jQuery file here to see that I didn't simply forget to return the elements or something like that.
https://completeset.com/includes/js/jquery-2.0.3.js

Comment: If you use an old version of jQuery does the same behavior exist? Are you loading other jQuery Plugins? If so one of them may be messing with the `.show()` and `.hide()` functions. What happens is you use `.css({ display : 'none' })` and `.css({ display : '' })` instead of `.show()` and `.hide()`?

Comment: I just remembered that had to attach event handlers to show and hide using the code from this: http://maximeparmentier.com/2012/11/06/bind-show-hide-events-with-jquery/ That's probably my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was using code from http://maximeparmentier.com/2012/11/06/bind-show-hide-events-with-jquery/ to attach event handlers to the show and hide functions. In doing so, I failed to notice the warning in the comments that the function as given breaks chaining on the show and hide functions. The comment that points that out also gives a solution to the problem.